# Aliasing Issues in Sub Band Coding

Tags: filter-design, bandwidth, time-frequency, aliasing, multirate

The general structure of Sub-Band Coding (SBC) is shown below:
[image]

The diagram shows that after each of the analysis filters, decimation is performed by a factor M which corresponds to the number of channels. Would this not result in aliasing when this decimation by N is performed for the higher frequency sub-bands and why is DDC not required in each path to translate each sub-band to baseband before performing the decimation and thus avoiding aliasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just misjudging what the [CHANNEL] block does: this is just saying "all the bits that fall out of the different quantizers/encoders get transmitted".

It's especially *not* an adder! Most books actually show this just as a "frame packer" or "interleaver".

Comment: Thank you for your response. My ambiguity is around the portion where decimation takes place, would that decimation not result in aliasing as the Fs would be reduced for each path?

Comment: that's a different question than what you're asking above, but what do you think is the job of the analysis filters?

Comment: I am sorry if I was not able to explain my question correctly. My idea is that the analysis filters separate the frequency bands but in that filtering the sample rate is still same as original. For example say my Fs is 100 MHz and I use analysis filters at 20-40MHz and 60-80 MHz. After I decimate the filtered signal by say a factor of 2, would not that cause aliasing for these bands?

Comment: you need to think about the relationship between your decimation and the bandwidths of these filters.